# Approximation of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that we have a self-adjoint operator $A$ on a finite-dimensional normed space such that $||A|| \leq 1$.  Can we approximate $A$ by an operator of the form $\tilde{A}=\sum_{n=1}^S \alpha_n R_n$ where $\alpha_s \in [-1, 1]$ and $R_j$ are mutually orthogonal projections?